# Symfony4 Twig Extension return image path

Tags: symfony, symfony4

I want to create a TwigExtension Function in Symfony4 in order to display images based on a string property in the view.

I have installed the assets: `"symfony/asset": "^4.4",`

In lower versions of Symfony I could to this with `AssetsHelper::getUrl()` -> Returns the public url/path of an asset.

I am not sure how can I achieve this in Symfony4 with "Twig".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is a bit different.

So This is what i did:

In webpackencore config i had to add this in order to have the files copied to the public folder:

```
.copyFiles({
        'from': './assets/img',
        'to': 'images/[path][name].[ext]'
    })
```

Then in my extension class the function looks like this:

```
/**
 * @param $type
 *
 * @return mixed
 */
public function showPaymentTypeIcon($type)
{
    $sImagePath = '/build/images/payment-icons';

    switch($type) {
        case 'card':
        default:
            $assetImagePath = $sImagePath.'/credit.svg';
            break;

        case 'sofort':
            $assetImagePath = $sImagePath.'/sofort.svg';
            break;

    }

    $oPackage = new Package(new EmptyVersionStrategy());

    return $oPackage->getUrl($assetImagePath);
}
```

So instead of `AssetsHelper` now we have to use `Package` as described here: https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/asset.html#asset-packages